# JQuery-Set value for empty dropdown from a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown box, It has no values in them. I have to set it preselected with a value available in a variable. This is what I have done but it does not set this value.

```
if(condition)
{
    var selectedVal = "myValue";                
    $("#myDropDownId").val(selectedVal);
}
```

as per info from google, the above one works when there are options already available in the dropdown.

I tried with the below as well

```
if(condition)
{
    var selectedVal = "myValue";                
    $("#myDropDownId option:selected").val(selectedVal);
 }
```

What is the correct syntax for this please?

Comment: Do you mean there are no `option` elements inside the `select`? If that's the case, you probably want to add one with a value/text matching the value of your variable, rather than trying to set the select value.

Comment: why using drop down when you need to select a single value; in any case if you want to select a value you need to have it available as one of the options

Comment: @StewieFG. Are you still having difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your first example is the correct method and should work fine; see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/THHxS/).

Are you using Firefox? If so, don't forget it keeps the state of a form on refresh, and does not pick the default values. Try pressing CTRL+F5 to force it to completely refresh the page and reset the form to initial defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var selectedVal = "myValue";
$("#myDropDownId").append('<option selected="true" value=' + selectedVal + '>' + 
                            selectedVal + '</option>');​
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jS7vv/2/)

(You can delete the `selected="true"` part if you don't want that option be selected)

Answer (score 0):

add this in your select

```
<option value="myValue">MY VALUEEEEE</option>
```